# $_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"] not set by nginx

Tags: php, apache, nginx, centos

I have installed `nginx` on my server. Now i don't get `$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]` variable which was working in Apache.

How to get this?

Comment: have you confirmed that http requests actually contain it?

Comment: Does this blog post help? http://blog.joshdzielak.com/blog/2011/06/24/nginx-gzip-and-request-headers/

Comment: @eis yes it was working on apache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally found solution by editing /etc/nginx/proxy.inc

proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding ""

to

proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding $http_accept_encoding

Answer (score 0):

When you run PHP-FPM with NGINX, php will see the $_SERVER variables in a totally different way (this is because of the default passing of server parameters to fcgi scripts in nginx).

Here's how $_SERVER variables will be seen by php when ran as php-fpm:
Code:
Array ( [USER] => nobody [HOME] => / [FCGI_ROLE] => RESPONDER [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /usr/local/www/www.example.com/public_html/example/index.php [Content-Type] => multipart/form-data [QUERY_STRING] => upload=true [REQUEST_METHOD] => POST [CONTENT_LENGTH] => 40403 [SCRIPT_NAME] => /example/index.php [REQUEST_URI] => /site/index.php?upload=true [DOCUMENT_URI] => /example/index.php [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /usr/local/www/www.example.com/public_html [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1 [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1 [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => nginx/0.7.65 [REMOTE_ADDR] => 193.110.48.4 [REMOTE_PORT] => 9971 [SERVER_ADDR] => 192.168.1.10 [SERVER_PORT] => 80 [SERVER_NAME] => www.example.com [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200 [HTTP_HOST] => www.example.com [HTTP_ORIGIN] => http://www.example.com [HTTP_X_FILE_SIZE] => 40403 [HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH] => XMLHttpRequest [HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL] => max-age=0 [HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE] => Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT [HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH] => 40403 [HTTP_X_FILE_NAME] => nokia-6300-yahoo.jpg [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_8; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.1 Safari/533.17.8 [HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE] => multipart/form-data [HTTP_REFERER] => http://www.example.com/example/index.php [HTTP_ACCEPT] => */* [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-us [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate [HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive [PHP_SELF] => /example/index.php [REQUEST_TIME] => 1282822862 )

Note the HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE, HTTP_X_FILE_SIZE, HTTP_X_FILE_NAME and **other HTTP_* variables.**

here  is a simple php function that will regulate these header values into apache like ones.

```
 function getallheaders() {
    $replace_array = array('CONTENT_TYPE' => 'Content-Type',
                    'CONTENT_LENGTH' => 'Content-Length',
                    'X_FILE_SIZE' => 'X-File-Size',
                    'X_FILE_NAME' => 'X-File-Name');
    foreach($_SERVER as $h=>$v) {
        $h = str_replace("HTTP_", "", $h);
        $h = $replace_array[$h];
        $headers[$h] = $v;
    }
    return $headers;
```

}

Comment: but my nginx is not passing HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING variable